# Multiple Database Records with Same Primary Key

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I need to store relationships where a single `attribute_id` may be visible in multiple `store_id` and I was trying to use `attribute_id` as the primary key. It would be something like this:

```
+--------------+----------+
| attribute_id | store_id |
+--------------+----------+
| 147          | 1        |
| 147          | 2        |
+--------------+----------+
```

But Magento doesn't see that with good eyes as it returns the exception `Item (foo) with the same ID "x" already exists.`

What is the best solution for that problem?

Comment: I think you can't do that as Primary Key cannot be duplicated in any database.

Comment: the best solution is to create new ID as primary key

Comment: @magefms when I tried setting both of them as primary keys, the database accepted it, but not Magento... Anyway, I've thought about creating a new ID as primary key, but couldn't get a solution on how to update the relationship when it has too.. It is worth saying that I don't have much experience with databases management so if you know some technique or has some link to share on how to deal with this situation, I would be thankful. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, I created a relationship `id` column (like @magefms recommended) which happens to be the primary key, and whenever I need to update this relationship, I delete all the records that contains an specific `attribute_id` and create it again. To do that I implemented the following function in my model:

```php
public function deleteByColumnValue($column, $value)
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($column, $value);
    foreach($collection as $item) {
        $item->delete();
    }
}
```

This function is probably available somewhere across Mage_Core, but I couldn't find it. Anyway, then on the controller save action, this is how I call it:

```php
Mage::getModel('module/model')->deleteByColumnValue('attribute_id', $storeId);
```

Hope this is helps someone!